# Adjacent lists: trying to improve this script using a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to improve this script, which returns a bool if an adjacent item is equal.

```
from typing import List, Dict, TextIO, Tuple
def adjacent_match(L: List[str]) -> bool:
"""Return True iff two adjacent items in L are equal.

>>> adjacent_match(['A', 'B', 'B'])
True
>>> adjacent_match(['A', 'B', 'A'])
False
"""

result = False

for index in range(len(L)):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return result
    elif index == 0:
        result = L[index] == L[index + 1]
    elif 0 < index < (len(L) - 1):
        result = (L[index] == L[index + 1] or L[index] == L[index - 1])
    elif index == (len(L) - 1):
        result = L[index] == L[index - 1]
    if result == True:
        return result

return result
```

So I feel like this script can be improved using a `while` loop, but hasn't work for me, my goal is to make it shorter without using modules, any advice?

Comment: sounds like a "Here you go - this code does what it does - rewrite it using a while" - homework ..

Comment: @PatrickArtner it was homework and the code worked, but I'm asking because the length of the code bugs me, and I think a `while` loop might work better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run through each element in the input array (using an index), but the last one to avoid an IndexError, and compare it with the next element:

```python
def adjacent_match(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
      if arr[i] == arr[i + 1]:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Would you mind pointing out where in my script I can get IndexError?

Comment: @S.. just change len(arr) - 1 by len(arr) and you will get an IndexError (unless arr is an empty array, in that case the for loop will never execute). If you array has size 3 then the last element is at index 2, but the last iteration will try to access the array at index 3 (arr[i + 1])

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (which is in-built, you don't need to import) to check adjacency condition:

```
def adjacent_match(L):
    for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]):
        if x == y:
            return True
    return False
```

**Sample runs**:

```
>>> adjacent_match(['A', 'B', 'B'])
True
>>> adjacent_match(['A', 'B', 'A'])
False
```

Comment: when using one built in , use two: `return any(x==y for x,y in zip(L, L[1:]) )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` to iterate through the items in the list and also keep track of the item's position in the list.

For each item in the second and subsequent position, compare it to the previous item.

```
def adjacent_match(L):
    for position, item in enumerate(L):
        if position == 0:
            continue
        if item == L[position-1]:
            return True

    return False
```